# pushViewController из TabBarController

Tags: swift, uikit

Есть кастомный tabBarController с пятью табами, и нужно что бы при нажатии на один из них отрабатывал pushViewController.  Я уже и через индексы пробовал перебирать, никак не выходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так перебираю индексы, и пробовал к нужным из них ставить pushViewController

Comment: покажите код, как вы пытались сделать

Comment: нужен эффект `pushViewController` или именно вызов? Если последнее, то для чего оно вам?

Comment: да, нужен именно эффект pushViewControlller

Comment: @KlimPostironin да, нужен именно эффект) буду очень благодарен

Comment: @EvgeniyMaglena, если честно, всё ещё не совсем понятно. Первый вопрос: то есть при нажатии на TabBarItem нужен переход справа налево? Предполагаю, что вам нужна анимация. Второй вопрос: по вашей задумке, если я перехожу из 3-го таба в 1-й, у меня идёт анимация слева направо?

Comment: @KlimPostironin приложение так написано, мне его надо сверстать. И там во втором табе такой прикол. 
но он было сделать на swiftUI, скорее всего там это сделать проще.  
Но я вроде нашел выход, через кастомное модальное представление